# Как реализован биндинг к ViewModel в WPF? Хочу что-то похожее сделать

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, рефлексия, viewmodel

Хочу написать аналог привязки свойств ViewModel в WPF, только привязка будет к другому приложению. Столкнулся с трудностями приведения типов. В WPF, к примеру, в свойство DataContext окна добавляется ViewModel, которая реализует интерфейс INotifyPropertyChanged и тот, насколько я понимаю, нужен лишь для генерации событий. Каким образом внешний код получает доступ к свойствам каждой конкретной ViewModel зная только названия свойств и объект? Ведь чтобы добраться до свойств, нужно заранее знать класс, подключить пространство имен(как?) и попытаться привести к конкретной ViewModel. Или есть другой способ?

Comment: Рефлексия же, вы далее метку такую установили

Comment: Так то да, но вопрос вот в чем. Можно ли из object через Type вытащить все и создать из него  исходный производный класс(в этой же сборке)? Я такого не нашел. Про `object as` и `(class)object` я знаю, но это вообще никак не помогает, а разбирать сборку на части и сравнивать с каждым классом странно как-то. И не знаю как этого избежать. И я не могу понять как из строкового названия типа объявить тип в коде.

Comment: При чем тут строковое название? Ничего не понятно. У вас есть объект и есть название свойства, какая проблема прочитать из этого объекта указанное свойство?

Comment: Название свойства передается как string. `PropertyChanged(nameof(property))`. У меня на входе `SomeViewModel` в виде `object` и его свойство в виде `string` - `nameof(property)`. Как при помощи этого сделать `SomeViewModel.Property`?

Comment: В JavaScript, например, есть методы позволяющие вытаскивать составляющие по средством передачи в определенный метод объекта строку. В C# такое тоже есть?

Comment: Ну рефлексия же, вы читали документацию? Смотрели какие члены есть у класса `Type`?

Comment: 1. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperty?view=netcore-3.1#System_Type_GetProperty_System_String_ 2. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue?view=netcore-3.1#System_Reflection_PropertyInfo_GetValue_System_Object_

Comment: Огромное спасибо, вырешили мою проблему. Я просто самоучка, и часто додумываю себе препядствия. В видеокурсах такого не показали. А гуглил как получить доступ к свойствам производного класса, везде пишут "никак". Получается что сильная типизация это когда вроде нельзя, но если очень хочется то JavaScript?) Если честно, то я думал что ответ будет, что в C# это не реализовать и фремворк написан с применением чего-то типа C++. Вздохнул с облегчением, буду читать. Еще раз спасибо и с Наступающим Н.Г.